# Ember Image Views performance tips?

Tags: performance, ember.js

could anyone point a strategy to display ember image views without having a delay to paint rendered images?

I find myself in the case, where the all my app views are painted immediately, except image views which require a short time to be shown, and then they appear all at the same time.

This behavior is initially only recognized on mobile browsers.

Wondering whether there is something to do/tweak at ember-level, currently testing on phonegap-mobile devices accessing to local images.

Comment: Could you provide some code or better a JsFiddle for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to show all the views at the same time (image and non-image views).

You can use [jQuery load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for detecting when the views have completely loaded. I assume that you have a parent view `App.MainView` that wraps all your views and an associated template `templateName: 'app/templates/layouts/main'`. You initially set the parent view not to display, and in the `didInsertElement`, use jQuery `load` to show it when the parent view and all child views have completely loaded:

```
<!-- 'app/templates/layouts/main' -->

<div class="toggle" style="display:none">

   <!-- all child views go here -->

</div>
```

...

```
App.MainView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'app/templates/layouts/main',

  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$().load( function(el){
       $(el).find('.toggle').show();
    });
  }
});
```